# woocommerce change currency per category

Tags: functions, filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to display a different currency on a specific category within my Woocommerce store. Specifically, this category is full of items that can only be purchased through myCred points. The rest of the store has items that can be purchased normally.

I know I can use the `is_product_category` function in my functions.php to target a specific category but how do I go about telling Woocommerce to use a specific currency in just one category?

Comment: Please check this may help you: https://chrislema.com/woocommerce-product-pricing/

Comment: You can filter and display specific currency for specific category. But how do you think any payment gateway(paypal etc) is going to accept multiple product with multiple currecny type? Either you need to  limit each category checkout at a time or convert all currency to one single. Let us know what do you need.

Comment: Well thankfully I don't have to worry about how payment gateways such as  paypal will handle multiple currency types. I already have it set that these specific products can only be bought using the myCred payment method. So I want to limit those products to use the myCred points currency (it adds it's points to the selection of currencies you can choose for your store).The other products can be purchased normally with US dollars so paypal and other payment methods never have to deal with multiple currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the `woocommerce_currency` filter.

```
function change_woocommerce_currency( $currency ) {
    if ( is_product_category( 'my-special-cat' ) ) {
        $currency = 'myCred' // or whatever the currency symbol is
    }
    return $currency;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', 'change_woocommerce_currency' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't seem to work for what I want to do. I tried using an "if" statement on price.php. I set it up like this                           `if ( $product_id == 14945 ){
        echo "100 GOLD";
        }if( $product_id == 14949 ){
        echo "300 GOLD";
        }if( $product_id == 14950 ){
        echo "750 GOLD";
        }if( $product_id == 14951 ){
        echo "1500 GOLD";
        }else{
        echo $product->get_price_html();
        }`

Comment: @SpyderTech what happens what you try this method? You said your plugin adds a new currency to the currency drop down under `WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency Options > Currency`? If you inspect the element and look at the `<option>`s in the `<select>` field, what is the value of your new currency `<option>`?

Comment: The value is `MYC`. It changes the symbol but it doesn't actually change what the currency is. So if item X is $4.99 but costs 100 MYC it is showing up as Gold4.99 instead of 100 Gold.

Comment: I think I understand. You want a price conversion to happen? Normally despite what currency you are using you set the numerical value that you want. If the product cost 100 gold you set the price field to 100 and the currency to MYC. But it sounds like you want to be able to set two prices, one for GOLD100 and one for $4.99. This is different than your original question.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear but I do believe I stated it correctly.I want to display in 2 different currencies on the site. But I only want to display the myCred points in a single category, not the entire site. In the end I don't think it's possible. Even when I change the currency in Woocommerce settings an item with the price of $10 is showing up as GOLD 10 rather than GOLD 100. I think my best bet would be hard coding a replacement price using the `product_id` variable or just hiding the price on all items in that category altogether.

Comment: No apologies needed. You did state it correctly. I interpreted it wrong. Showing two currencies at the same time adds something new. I would add a custom field for the gold value. Then code the single-product.php file or with a hook to display it. Then code the function to process it from the users account. It sounds like you kind of want a reward system of sorts.

Comment: Yes, it's a reward system. A hook or a filter would be good. So I would add a custom field called "Gold" or something and then add a hook that if there is a value in that field, display said value?

Comment: How to check product type in this woocommerce_currency filter?